# Single container Have TWO fragments , How To Replace one fragment out of two?

Tags: android-layout, android

I have one container root in main.xml.
In that container I have added two fragments "Transaction" and "balance".
Basically after adding transaction balance should be updated and "transaction" fragment should be replaced with "Stats" Fragment.

Currently I am using the replace like :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.root, BalFrag).commit();
```

But above code is removing the "balance" fragment and adding new one after "transaction" fragment.

Comment: if you replacing the Fragment then which ever is showing currently will replace with new one, for e.g i just add three fragments (f1, f2, f3) in FrameLayout now i am replacing the fragment (f2 - which is currently showing) with fragment f4, then f2 is replaced with f4 and f1 and f3 remain as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 2 Fragments in a single container sounds like a bad idea to me but I think you should be able to replace just one fragment using something like

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("transaction"); // or keep a reference to it.
Fragment newFragment = getNewFragment() // whatever you do to get a fragment instance

FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.remove(oldFragment);
ft.add(R.id.root, newFragment, "Stats");
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Agreed with the first point--OP should be using two containers, even if both of those containers are within the same one.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I have fFirst and fSecond fragments

```
if (fFirst != null && fFirst.isVisible()) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fSecond);
} else {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fFirst);
}
```